# Appending an array in a while loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to append values from a newly created array to a previously created array, then run a while loop to do this 10,000 times. Here is what I have so far:

```
def evolve(m_all, pp_all, pv_all, tf, dt):
"""
Evolves the initial positions and initial velocites of particles for a given time step and total time, then 
updates their positions.

Parameters
----------
 m_all : np.ndarray
    1-D array containing masses for all particles, length N, where
    N is the number of particles.
pp_all : np.ndarray
    2-D array containing (x, y, z) positions for all particles. 
    Shape is (N, 3) where N is the number of particles.
pv_all : np.ndarray
    2-D array containing (x, y, z) velocities for all particles. 
    Shape is (N, 3) where N is the number of particles.
tf : float
    The total time to evolve the system.
dt : float
    Evolve system for time dt.

Returns
-------
partpos : N-D array
    N-D array with the updated particle postions for each time step, dt.
partvel : N-D array
    N-D array with the updated particle velocities for each time step, dt.

"""
partpos = np.zeros((10000, 3)) # create empty array with 10000 elements
partvel = np.zeros((10000, 3)) # create empty array with 10000 elements

t = 0 # initial time
i = 0

while t < tf:
    new_positions, new_velocities = \
        evolve_particles(pp_all, pv_all, m_all, dt)
    t += dt # add time step
    partpos[i] = new_positions[i]
    partvel[i] = new_velocities[i]
    i += 1
    pp_all = new_positions
    pv_all = new_velocities

return partpos, partvel
```

I am trying to append the newly created values from the new_positions and new_velocities array to the partpos and partvel array, but am getting the following error:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

How would I go about fixing this? Here are the inputs:

```
m_all = np.array([1.98e30, 5.972e24]) # the array of masses
N = len(m_all)
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1.5e11, 0, 0]) # an array of all the positions
pp_all = np.reshape(x, (N, 3)) # reshapes position array into Nx3 array
v = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 29779.5, 0]) # array of velocities
pv_all = np.reshape(v, (N, 3)) # reshapes velocity array into Nx3 array
tf = (2 * np.pi * 1.5e11) / 29779.5 # calculates total time 
dt = tf / 10e4 # calculate the time step
```

This code is supposed to model the orbit of the earth around the sun using 10,000 times steps. new_positions and new_velocities are each 2D arrays. Thanks!

Here is the evolve_particles function:

```
def evolve_particles(pp_all, pv_all, m_all, dt):
""" 
Evolve particles in time via leap-frog integrator scheme. 

Parameters
----------
pp_all : np.ndarray
    2-D array containing (x, y, z) positions for all particles. 
    Shape is (N, 3) where N is the number of particles.
pv_all : np.ndarray
    2-D array containing (x, y, z) velocities for all particles. 
    Shape is (N, 3) where N is the number of particles.
m_all : np.ndarray
    1-D array containing masses for all particles, length N, where
    N is the number of particles.
dt : float
    Evolve system for time dt.

Returns
-------
Updated particle positions and particle velocities, each being a 2-D
array with shape (N, 3), where N is the number of particles.

""" 

# Make copies of position/velocity arrays that we can modify in-place.
pp = pp_all.copy()
pv = pv_all.copy()

N = len(m_all)             # Number of particles in system
dims = pp_all.shape[-1]    # Dimensionality of problem

# Compute net force vectors on all particles
forces = netGravForces(m_all, pp_all)

# Leap-frog method takes two half-steps (first dimension of acc array)
acc = np.zeros([2,N,dims])

# Leap-frog integrator takes two half-steps
step = 0
while step < 2:      

    # Loop over particles, compute acceleration,
    # update positions and velocities
    for k in xrange(N):

        # Rec-calculate acceleration at each half-step
        acc[step,k] = forces[k] / m_all[k]

        # Update position on first half-step, velocity on second
        if step == 0:
            pp[k,:] = pp[k] + pv[k] * dt + 0.5 * acc[0,k] * dt**2
        else:
            pv[k,:] = pv[k] + 0.5 * (acc[0,k] + acc[1,k]) * dt

    step += 1

return pp, pv
```

This is the error message with the line that produced the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-843691efebda> in <module>()
----> 1 partpos, partvel = evolve(m_all, pp_all, pv_all, tf, dt)

<ipython-input-22-f0eb2f7f6e98> in evolve(m_all, pp_all, pv_all, tf, dt)
     38         t += dt # add time step
     39         while i < 10000:
---> 40             partpos[i] = new_positions[i]
     41             partvel[i] = new_velocities[i]
     42             i += 1

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: Can you post evolve_particles() method too?

Comment: What's the shape of the returning arrays from evolve_particles()  (new_positions, new_velocities) before you do the assignment?.. sounds like a problem with "i" index, trying to get something that's impossible to get from the arrays.

Comment: Which line produced the error?  Don't hide useful information.  Have youu attempted to print the `shape` of arrays at that point?

Comment: The shape of the array that evolve_particles() returns is (2, 3). I just posted the line that produced the error.

Comment: Why are you indexing a (2,3) array with `i`: `new_positions[i]`?

Comment: That could be my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop `while t < tf` in `evolve` will repeat 100,000 times.  That means the code expects `new_positions` to have 100,000 elements.  But the return value from `evolve_particles` is list with only 2 elements, because it is based on the number of elements in the `pp_all` input.  So you get an index error on the 3rd time through the loop.